# Question about quadratic maximum/minimum word problem with linear modeling

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the below problem from a textbook:

[image]

It goes through the solution. I don't get this part here:

[image]

This is a simple part, as this is just describing a linear equation. I thought I knew how to model these. Why is it not Q = 84,000 - 2,500p? In English, I can say we are starting at 84,000 subscribers, and deceasing 2,500 subscribers for every $1 we increase the price. It seems so easy! But in this problem they make me solve for b. I've done other linear equation problems where I didn't have to do this, so I'm a little confused.

*I guess what I'm confused about is, when reading a word problem, how do I know something is a starting value or a regular y/output value? knowing that will help me determine where I need to plug in these figures.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, $Q=84000$, $p=30$.  Try substituting these values into your proposed equation $$Q=84000-2500p$$ and see if you get a true statement.

To say that $Q$ is a linear function of $p$ is to say $$Q=ap+b$$ for some constants $a$ and $b$.  Equation of a straight line, right?  Now, we are told that $a=-2500$, so it remains to find $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach without calculating $b$ via an equation is also possible but you need to $\color{blue}{\text{cater for the case $p=30$}}$.

So, your approach should lead directly to

$$Q(p) = 84000 - 2500(p\color{blue}{-30})$$